# Maximize entropy under Kulback-Leibler divergence

Tags: inequalities, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, entropy

I posed [this question in math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4503894/64809), but have not received any answer. I would like to try my luck here.

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/66296/64809), it is to solve

\begin{align}
\max_p &-\int dy\,p(y)\ln p(y) \\
0&=1-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(y)dy\\
0&=1-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y^2p(y)dy\\
0&=c+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\ln p(y)\,dy
\end{align}
I can certainly apply the calculus of variation. However I would like to directly apply Jensen's inequality.

Here is my attempt at the solution. But I am not certain of the validity of the last inequality. Would someone please correct me?
\begin{align}
&\int dy\, p(y)\ln \frac1{p(y)}  \\
=& \int dy\,p\ln\frac{\exp\big(-\lambda_1y^2-\frac{\lambda_2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}2}\frac{\ln p}{p}\big)}{p}+\lambda_1 \int dy\, y^2 p +\lambda_2 \int dy\,e^{-\frac{y^2}2}\ln p \quad \text{where} p:=p(y) \\
\le&\ \ln\int dy \exp\Big(-\lambda_1y^2-\frac{\lambda_2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}2}\frac{\ln p}{p}\Big)+\lambda_1 \int dy\, y^2 p +\frac{\lambda_2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int dy\,e^{-\frac{y^2}2}\ln p
\end{align}
where the last inequality comes from Jensen's inequality applied to $\ln$ which is convex. The equality is reached when and only when $p=p_1$ such that $\exp\big(-\lambda_1y^2-\frac{\lambda_2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}2}\frac{\ln p_1}{p_1}\big)=z(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)p_1$ for some positive function $z(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ so that
\begin{align}
\int dy\,p_1(y)&=1, \\
\int dy\,y^2p_1(y)&=1, \\
\int dy\,\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2}p_1(y)&=-c. 
\end{align}
We have
$$\int dy\, p_1\ln\frac1p_1=\ln z(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)+\lambda_1-\lambda_2c.$$
However, I am not sure if
$$\int dy\, p\ln\frac1p\le\int dy\, p_1\ln\frac1p_1,\quad\forall \text{ probability measure }p.$$

---

Now I think it may not be so easy. Jensen's inequality may only be applicable to when the constraint is linear to the probability distribution $p(y)$. But there may be a surprising solution.

Comment: It seems to me that there are probability distributions arbitrarily far from the Gaussian in the sense of KL divergence that are arbitrarily close in terms of their entropy and variance. Just take the Gaussian, make the probability almost zero on a small-ish interval, and increase the probability proportionally everywhere else. So I think your problem is unsolvable in the sense that there is no maximum, i.e., the supremum is never attained.

Comment: @WillSawin: I like your example which is correct by itself. However, you may have read the question in reverse. It is to bound the KL divergence within a set distance from the Gaussian and away from the entropy of any probability distribution as far as possible. The problem is convex in both the objective function and constraint. So the supremum is achieved via the Kuhn-Tucker condition.